# <select> tag returning weird integers,

Tags: php, html

```html
<select name="pharmacies" id="pharmacies">
    <option value="1">őrangyal</option>
    <option value="2">Tulipán</option>
    <option value="3">Cédrus</option>
    <option value="4">Nagylak</option>
</select>
```

Above code returning weird integers like "+241" for the code below.

```php
echo($_POST['pharmacies']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the browser's developer tool, select the network tab and the post request.
Paste the submitted data.

make sure that your PHP script has at the beginning.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

var_dump is displaying the variable type and contents.
This will show all submitted data values in order to understand what is the PHP input from the HTTP POST method.
After understanding it. you can convert this variable to integer by:

```
(int) $_POST['pharmacies']
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to phpand not evenrealylikeit. :)var_dump($_POST);
that was the problem

Comment: var_dump is displaying the variable type and contents.
This will show all submitted data values in order to understand what is the PHP input from the HTTP POST method.
After understanding it. you can convert this variable to integer by:
(int) $_POST['pharmacies']

Comment: This is, so far, not actually an answer to the question. You are giving basic debugging advice here, in order to get some clarification on the very unclear question - that should not be posted as an answer, but handled in comments.

Comment: His wrote what is he sending and the incorrect output of one of the sent parameters.
My answer gives him clear guidelines in order for better understanding where is his problem.